# Java replace string ignore spaces

Tags: java

```
String msg = "123 tEsT";
System.out.println(msg.replaceAll("(?i)test", "****"));
```

Result:
123 ****

```
String msg = "123 tE sT";
System.out.println(msg.replaceAll("(?i)test", "****"));
```

Result:
"123 tE sT"

But I want to replace ignore spaces with result: "123 ****"

What i should change? To get from "123 tE sT" this "123 ****"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the blanks with `*` wildcard to your regexp:

```
System.out.println(msg.replaceAll("(?i)t *e *s *t", " ****"));
```

Comment: You should drop the .replace(" ",  "")

Comment: @YuriSchimke - thanks, copied from the answer instead of the question. edited now

Comment: System.out.println(msg.replaceAll("(?i)t *e *s *t", " ****"));